# numeric precision in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

I have a table with a `FLOAT` column, as defined in [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28285/sqlqr06.htm#CHDBBHHE).
I insert a number with 52 binary digits (not counting the initial 1 which is implicit), yet I see that oracle requires only 50 digits to correctly store it. How could that be?

```
create table numeric_types2(
    f1 float(60)
);
insert into numeric_types2 SELECT BIN_TO_NUM(
    1,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,1
                                      ) FROM DUAL;
```

and then:

```
select to_char(cast(f1 as float(49)), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'),
       to_char(cast(f1 as float(50)), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'),
       to_char(cast(f1 as float(51)), 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
from root.numeric_types2;
```

return:

```
10000000000004,    10000000000001,    10000000000001
```

why is that? am i missing some elementary floating-point math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs also state](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-10D4D073-866D-4BD4-B3E9-ED153D505A6A):

> The FLOAT data type is a subtype of NUMBER

So it's a `number` under the covers and

> To convert from binary to decimal precision, multiply n by 0.30103

Plugging the numbers in:

```
49 * 0.30103 = 14.75047
50 * 0.30103 = 15.05150
51 * 0.30103 = 15.65356
```

So `float(50)` and `float(51)` correspond to `number(16)`, whereas `float(49)` is `number(15)`

You can verify this by taking a `dump` of the values:

```
create table numeric_types2 (
    f1 float(60), n1 number
);
insert into numeric_types2 
with rws as (
  select BIN_TO_NUM(
    1,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
    0,1) n from dual
)
  select n, n from rws;

select dump ( f1 ), dump ( n1 ), 
       dump ( cast ( n1 as float(50) ) ) df50, 
       dump ( cast ( n1 as float(49) ) ) df49
from   numeric_types2;

DUMP(F1)                                 DUMP(N1)                                 DF50                                     DF49                                  
Typ=2 Len=9: 200,46,4,60,97,28,38,5,98   Typ=2 Len=9: 200,46,4,60,97,28,38,5,98   Typ=2 Len=9: 200,46,4,60,97,28,38,5,98   Typ=2 Len=8: 200,46,4,60,97,28,38,6
```

Note that

`dump ( f1 ) = dump ( n1 ) = dump ( cast ( n1 as float(50) ) )`

Only casting the number as `float(49)` gives a different value.

Finally note that the docs also contain this recommendation:

> Oracle FLOAT is available for you to use, but Oracle recommends that
> you use the BINARY_FLOAT and BINARY_DOUBLE data types instead, as they
> are more robust

Comment: thanks! commenting here for context: this means that if you're using cx_Oracle python driver, than `FLOAT(50)` is the lowest precision capable of holding a number with 53 binary bits (not counting the first implicit 1), which is lost when converted to python's float, and truncated to `0x1.0000000000000p+53`

Answer (score 1):

The linked doc page says

> A FLOAT value is represented internally as NUMBER

Could it be that the number of binary digits is rounded to a number of decimal digits?

Also, converted to decimal, the hexadecimal numbers are:

```
10000000000001 -> 4503599627370497
10000000000004 -> 4503599627370500
```

So it looks to me like the number was converted to a decimal representation internally, rounded to 14 or 15 decimal digits - 497 would round to 500.

Note that in latin language, a digit is base-10 (digitus = finger).

Answer (score 1):

As it already was said, this is because there's a `number` implementation underneath this type. And as you can check with the below query, binary precision is completely ignored:

1. Binary precision is rounded *up* to the decimal precision N.
2. The number is mathematically rounded to the *first* N significant positions (e.g. for N = 2: 101 becomes 100, 106 becomes 110).
3. The number is stored in `number` format, having the first N significant digits from step 2 and scaled by the scale of the original number (e.g. the result has the same length, but N significant digits).

```
with a as (
  select level as l,
    cast(level as float(1)) as c,
    cast(level as float(2)) as c2,
    cast(level as float(3)) as c3,
    cast(level as float(4)) as c4,
    cast(level as float(6)) as c6,
    cast(level as float(7)) as c7
  from dual
  connect by level < 121
)
select a.*,
  dump(c, 16) as cd,
  dump(c4, 16) as c4d,
  dump(power(10, l), 16) as scale
from a
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4634840019effdde3f3700ce12dd0bf9) here.

As you see, for precision 1-3 you can store only one digit, for 4-6 - two digits, etc. Also you can observe, that scale changes every two decimal digits (the first two bytes in `dump`, column `scale`).

So the storage is: two bytes for scale, and up to 20 bytes for precision, where each byte hold numbers from 0 to 99. But I cannot figure out where they've lost two digits at precision 38 (19*2, should be 20).