# Oracle Byte Size for number

Tags: oracle

I am get very confused when trying to work out the size in bites of number data types for Oracle.

How would I go about working out the size of say if columns had either of these two data types -

```
NUMBER(38,0)
NUMBER(4,2)
```

I understand that the first one would mean records would be up to 38 numbers long and the second one would be similar to 1234.56. I just dont know how to use that knowledge to calucate the bytes for the columns.

The Oracle resources I've found say;

> NUMBER [ (p [, s]) ]
>
> Number having precision p and scale s. The precision p can range from
> 1 to 38. The scale s can range from -84 to 127. Both precision and
> scale are in decimal digits. A NUMBER value requires from 1 to 22
> bytes.

Does that mean for example that NUMBER(38,0) could be up to 38*22 = 836 bytes and NUMBER(4,2) could be up to 6*22 = 132 bytes?

I would really appreciate some help clarifying.

Comment: You seem confused by "number" vs. "digit". `number(38.0)` may have up to 38 ***digits***, not up to 38 ***numbers***. A **number** (be it in `number(38,0)` or in `number(4,2)` format) may take up to 38 bytes - for the entire number, no matter how many digits, algebraic sign, etc. Any column of `number` data type, with any precision and scale, will take up to 38 bytes. (Note also that `number(4,2)` means up to four significant digits **including** the two decimal places; so something like 38.20 or perhaps -93.95; but not what you wrote, which would require `number(6,2)`.)

Comment: Thank you for clarification on the number(4,2) part.

Comment: Still confused as to how many bytes either option would take up.

Comment: @mathguy number can take [up to 22](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78) bytes in storage

Comment: @astentx - Yep - meant to write 22 but by the time I got there I wasn't paying enough attention anymore. Good clarification. (The OP already knew "22", just didn't know what that means.)

Comment: @StudentWork I've done aome research on number atorage, you may check it in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65662609/numeric-precision-in-oracle/65672655#65672655). In short: 1 byte for scale, 1 byte for sign and up to 20 bytes for precision. In storage number is divided into decimal pairs (starting from the right) and each pair is stored as one byte. Then it is multiplied by scale to represent at display time. So `10^X` will take 2 bytes (store `1` and its scale), number containing `N` decimal places will take `N/2 +1` bytes (`N/2` for the digits and 1 for scale)

Comment: I've tried to look at that and your answer and I am still very very confused. I am not familiar with float so that answer only makes things more confusing for me. Would you be able to use the examples above or similar numbers so I can see numbers in context? I find it hard to sometimes understand with N and X, I do much better with examples.